Weird Line separating in VSTACK
As shown in this Photo of problem
There is a weird grey line separating the items in my Vstack was wondering how to get rid of this.
I'm confused on why this shows up because I've not written anything in my lines about this separator and can't get rid of it without fully deleting my button.
  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(assignments) { assignment in
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Assignment", text: Binding(
                            get: { assignment.assignmentName },
                            set: { newValue in
                                if let index = assignments.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == assignment.id }) {
                                    assignments[index].assignmentName = newValue
                                }
                            }
                        ))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                        TextField("Grade", text: Binding(
                            get: { assignment.grade },
                            set: { newValue in
                                if let index = assignments.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == assignment.id }) {
                                    assignments[index].grade = newValue
                                }
                            }
                        ))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                        TextField("Weight", text: Binding(
                            get: { assignment.weight },
                            set: { newValue in
                                if let index = assignments.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == assignment.id }) {
                                    assignments[index].weight = newValue
                                }
                            }
                        ))
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteAssignment)

                // Add Row Button



                ZStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                assignments.append(AssignmentRow())
                                print("Add Assignment Button pressed!")
                            }
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                Text("Add Assignment")
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                            }
                            .padding(-8)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(GrowingButton(backgroundColor: .blue)) // have to add the backgroundcolor now :)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                    }
                    
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.white) // Set row background to white to remove grey
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) // Center align the frame


            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            
                

        } // end of our VSTACK from start
        .background(Color.white) // Set background color to white
        
    }

Thank you
I've tried to remove the borders.
Change the button styles.
A few other things and nothing has worked.

you could try using VStack (spacing: 0) {...}
